# Replace to work with dynamic pattern of replace all characters except the one given in dynamic string

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have a custom regex which works fine when doing test if string is matching the pattern or not, what when I am trying same to replace the characters that doesn't matches the pattern, it doesn't seems to work. Please help me understand, whats wrong I am doing in it:

This is my test code that works fine:

```
function alphaNumCheckOnKeyPress(event, elementId, customPattern) {

    var asciiCode = event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
    customPattern = (customPattern == undefined ? $('#'+elementId).attr('data-custom') : customPattern );
    var str = String.fromCharCode(asciiCode);
    var strToVal = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9' + customPattern + ']+$');

    if ( strToVal.test(str) )
        alert("test passed")
    else
        alert("test failed");

}
```

But when I am trying to use same pattern to replace characters then it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('paste blur', '.alphaNum', function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var customPattern = $(that).attr('data-custom') || "";
        $(that).val($(that).val().replace(new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9' + customPattern + ']+$', 'g'), ''));
    }, 0);
});
```

For instance, I am passing underscore (_) in custom pattern, that is to be allowed and should not be skipped from replacement.

Comment: You must be looking for `.replace(new RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9' + customPattern + ']+', 'g'), '')`. However, the `customPattern` needs a bit of escaping to avoid issues if there are `]`, `^`, ``\`` or `-` inside.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew, It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$'` pattern matches an entire string that only consists of word chars (letters, digits, `_`). You seem to want to remove all chars other than those you specify in the regex character class.

Thus, you need to make it a negated character class and remove anchors, `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string).

Also,  the `customPattern` needs a bit of escaping to avoid issues if there are `]`, `^`, `\` or `-` inside, which are the only chars that may have special meaning inside a JavaScript character class and to be treated as literal chars must be escaped.

```
.replace(new RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9' + customPattern.replace(/[\]^\\-]/g, '\\$&') + ']+', 'g'), '')
```